# server error 500 in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter.I have a controller called "User" and in that controller i have a method called "apply" which is bound to a form .With my ajax i am trying to implement a post request but in return i get internal server error 500 error .How i can fix this.I have my index.php page removed by an .htaccess file

```
 $.ajax({
       url:'http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/user/apply',
       type:'POST',
       data:{
           start:'3/3/2012',
           end  :'4/3/2012',
           reason:'sick'
           },
       success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    alert( data );
                },
        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                     alert( 'baler '+errorThrown );
                }
   });
```

Comment: 500 error is just a generic error saying that something went wrong. Check the log files to see what the actual error message is. Most likely a syntax error.

Comment: There is some error in the called file

Comment: @thamilan what do you mean.. called file is fine..i have used it without ajax and it works as expected

Comment: What do your log files report? Both Apache error and PHP error logs.

Comment: how can i see apache error log? and i haven't encountered any php errors my php error setting is this "error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT "

Comment: are you able to access `http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/user/apply` direct through URL? what it show?

Answer (score 0):

Try access vía url to method:

`http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/user/apply`

Or try `http://localhost/mycodeigniter/index.php/ci/user/appl`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the OP is doing the first one already.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using `HMVC`, you should typically access your controller's methods like this:

`your-local-project-path/controller-name/method-name`
So, the above request should work at following URL
`http://localhost/mycodeigniter/user/apply`

Comment: why should i omit /ci/ from url...it gives 404 not found error .which is obvious as it is not a valid path anymore

Comment: Because if your project is located under 'mycodeigniter', then why are you adding 'ci'?

Comment: my project is under directory mycodeigniter/ci/  .... ci is  a folder inside mycodeigniter

Comment: Then, I can't say much from the given code. There could be an issue with your route, or may be (most probably) a php error in your file/ controller/ or method!

Answer (score 0):

> This may help you

```
 /*
     |my sql date formate is 2012-3-4
     |and if not then first check your date in mysql and change your date according to this "date()" method    |used below
     */

    public function get_detail()
    {
        $start = $this->input->post('start');
        $end = $this->input->post('end');
        $reason = $this->input->post('reason');
        $start_date = date('Y-m-d',$start);
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d',$end);

        /*Pass data in model through function */

        $data = $this->model_name->function_name($start_date,$end_date,$reason);

    }
```